# Reactjs Multiple Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm working on React JS project. I have 4 dropdown button (select option). And all the dropdown will be coming from DB dynamically. So wanted to know what is the right method to implement.

Initially I had only 1 dropdown box, so implemented it with ajax call and append the values with `<option>` tag under `<select>` tag. Now I have 3 more dropdown, so do I need to call multiple ajax calls for all 4 box ? or is there any other ways to implement it ?

Please do suggest here. Because I don't want to implement in wrong way and revert back again.

Comment: Unless they are stored in different places you should be able to get the required values with one Ajax call and then store the results in the application state.

Comment: Are all your dropdown values independent of each other? Also, why use JQuery with reactjs?

Comment: Yes all are different values independent of each other. Jquery it's just single function with ajax call..

Comment: You can create a common component and just call it after you do an ajax call. It'll be much cleaner. And if each dropdown are different (has different options from different collections), then you would surely need to query for each of them.

Comment: why not returning all the data in one ajax call like this: `{option1: [], option2: [], option3: [], option4: []}`

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I'll look into it..

Comment: you could also look into using something other than jquery to make your ajax calls, there are lots of plugins for it. I am currently using axios which I find quite simple to use: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a small component for your dropdowns, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SelectOption extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <option value={this.props.dataItem.key}>{this.props.dataItem.val}</option>
        )
    }
}

class SimpleDropdown extends Component {

    render() {

        let options = [];

        if (this.props.selectableData) {
            const selectableData = this.props.selectableData;
            options = selectableData.map((dataItem) =>
                <SelectOption key={'option_' + dataItem.key} dataItem={dataItem} />
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} name={this.props.name} >
                    {options}
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SimpleDropdown;
```

You can use it in your parent component, something like this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import SimpleDropdown from './common/SimpleDropdown';


class Parentextends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // here you handle your ajax call or calls, depending on what you choose to go with
    }

    handleInputChange = (e) => {

        const target = e.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }


    render() {

        const ajaxResultFirst = ajaxResult.First;
        const ajaxResultSecond = ajaxResult.Second;
        const ajaxResultThird = ajaxResult.Third;
        const ajaxResultFourth = ajaxResult.Fourth;

        return (
            <section className="form">

                    <SimpleDropdown
                        name="FirstDropdown"
                        selectableData={ajaxResultFirst}
                        handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <SimpleDropdown
                        name="SecondDropdown"
                        selectableData={ajaxResultSecond}
                        handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <SimpleDropdown
                        name="ThirdDropdown"
                        selectableData={ajaxResultThird}
                        handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <SimpleDropdown
                        name="FourthDropdown"
                        selectableData={ajaxResultFourth}
                        handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />

            </section>
        );
    }
};

export default Parent;
```

Something like this should work. But I still recommend using a different plugin than jquery for making ajax requests, my first choice is axios https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios.